# How to create interface for object with a nested array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a simple GET request to list objects from an integration account in Angular / TypeScript. Here is a sample of the response:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "publicCertificate": "<publicCertificate>",
        "createdTime": "2021-03-11T19:50:03.50193Z",
        "changedTime": "2021-03-26T07:06:12.3232003Z"
      },
      "id": "/subscriptions/34adfa4f-cedf-4dc0-ba29-b6d1a69ab345/resourceGroups/testResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/testIntegrationAccount/certificates/<integrationAccountCertificateName>",
      "name": "<integrationAccountCertificateName>",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/certificates"
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "publicCertificate": "<publicCertificate>",
        "createdTime": "2021-05-27T12:45:33.455709Z",
        "changedTime": "2021-05-27T12:45:33.4564322Z"
      },
      "id": "/subscriptions/34adfa4f-cedf-4dc0-ba29-b6d1a69ab345/resourceGroups/testResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/testIntegrationAccount/certificates/<integrationAccountCertificateName>",
      "name": "<integrationAccountCertificateName>",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/certificates"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my current interface

```
export interface Certificate {
  value?: (ValueEntity)[] | null;
}

export interface ValueEntity {
  properties: Properties;
  id: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
}
export interface Properties {
  publicCertificate: string;
  createdTime: string;
  changedTime: string;
}
```

All I need to display is the `publicCertificate`, `id`, `name` and `type` values. Is there a simpler way to create the interface?

EDIT

Here is the service I am currently using

```
@Injectable()
export class integrationAccountService
{
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient, private api: ApiService) { }

  getcertificates(): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions : Object = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Token'
      }),
      responseType: 'json'
    };
    return this.httpclient.get('URL', httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Component

```
export class CertificateTableComponent {

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ValueEntity>;
  certificates: ValueEntity[] = [];
  columns: string[] = ['name', 'id', 'type', 'publicCertificate'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static:true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private _integrationAccountService: integrationAccountService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._integrationAccountService.getcertificates().subscribe(response => {
      this.certificates = response.data;

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.certificates);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    })

  }
}
```

Table to display data

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.name }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.id }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.type }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="publicCertificate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Public Certificate</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.publicCertificate }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: please post some code which you tried before, will be helpful to understand your problem

Comment: I have added code for the service, component and table

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON example data seems to be broken. You can try https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com to correct it. Once it is correct JSON we can much better help you.

Update:

In your service it would be helpful if you'd not return an 'Observable' but specify the type already there. In that way you will have better auto-completion when you access the result data somewhere else in the code:

this.http.get<Response<ExtLanguage[]>>(languagesURL)

```
@Injectable()
export class integrationAccountService
{
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient, private api: ApiService) { }

  getcertificates(): Observable<Certificate> {
    const httpOptions : Object = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Token'
      }),
      responseType: 'json'
    };
    return this.httpclient.get<Certificate>('URL', httpOptions);
  }
}
```

And in your component you have to do something with the result data first, there is no 'response.data'. One way is to just flatten your received data into a new structure:

```
export interface FlatRow {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    type: string;
    publicCertificate: string;
}

export class CertificateTableComponent {

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ValueEntity>;
  //certificates: ValueEntity[] = [];
  data: FlatRow[] = [];
  columns: string[] = ['name', 'id', 'type', 'publicCertificate'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static:true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private _integrationAccountService: integrationAccountService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._integrationAccountService.getcertificates().subscribe(response => {
      //this.certificates = response.data;
      this.data = [];
      if (response.value) {
          for (let entity of response.value) {
              let row: FlatRow = {
                  name: entity.name,
                  id: entity.id,
                  type: entity.type,
                  publicCertificate: entity.properties?.publicCertificate;
              };
          }
      }

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    })

  }
}
```

Comment: @JonaldMonday I updated my post, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response and explanation. When I try to implement your solution my table rows are empty and I am not sure why. I get no errors but the data does not make it to the table

Answer (score 1):

Try with below method which will convert your response object to appropriate response,

```
getResponseArrayList(response): Array<PropertiesSource> {
    let resultList: PropertiesSource[] = [];
    resultList = response.value.map(data => {
      let res : PropertiesSource = data.properties.key.keyVault;
      res.publicCertificate = data.properties.publicCertificate;
      return res;
    });
    console.log('result ', resultList);
    return resultList;
  }
```

Created [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gh8hmk) for your reference.

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @jonald consider to mark it as answer if it helps to resolve your query..